# How to clarify objects in a class and use them in a different one

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm not sure if I'm asking this correctly. What I want to do is be able to define my objects, a title and an image, in a different class and use it in ViewController.m. Currently, and I know this isn't good, I have a large if statement in ViewController.m defining all of these objects. 
So, it's like:

```
v = arc4random() % 10000;
if ([textBox.text isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
    if (v<=25) {
        titleLbl.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        titleLbl.text = @"Text";
        objectImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

And this type of code repeats for a few hundred lines. With this code currently, as you can probably guess, I'm getting this:

> WARNING: Slow defaults access for key ClientState took 0.076678 seconds, tolerance is 0.020000

I'm thinking that if  define all of these in a different class, this error won't happen. I might be wrong though. So, the questions are will defining the objects in a different class fix this warning and how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Only one branch of your `if` statement is actually running; the more likely problem is the image loading (or other file access).

Comment: Is there a way I can prevent the image from loading until I need it?

Comment: It looks like that's what you're already doing, depending on what `objectImg.image` is used for.

Comment: If I have 50 images, would that affect anything? Only one loading at a time, but 50 in file.